# Bitwise Extract Vector in ASIMD instruction (ARM platform)

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

I want to implement bitwise extract vector instruction in ASIMD assembly instruction. Let me put it this way that in ARMv7 NEON instructions, suppose I have some values inside `q15` and `q11`, and I have:

```
"vext.8 d30, d30, d22, #4 \n\t"
"vext.8 d31, d31, d23, #4 \n\t"
```

As you can see here, I'm extracting 4-byte elements from the bottom end of `d22` and 4-byte elements from the top end of `d30`. Then I combine them into one 64-bit register `d30` (first instruction above). The same operation is done on the second half of the `q` vectors (`d31` and `d23`). Now, I want to implement the exact same logic in ARMv8 ASIMD instructions. The replacement instruction for `vext` in ASIMD is `ext` and it's defined as:

> EXT Vd.(T), Vn.(T), Vm.(T), #index
>
> Bitwise extract (vector). Where (T) is either 8B or 16B. The index is an immediate value in the range 0 to nelem((T))-1.

My question is, How can I use this instruction to construct the same logic in my two SIMD vector registers `v15` and `v11` for example.

Answer (score 2):

You should first note that in Aarch64, registers are not organised in the same way. In Aarch32, Q15 is {D31, D30}. In Aarch64, D31 is the bottom of Q31, which can be described as V31 when speaking about elements.

There is no direct equivalent in Aarch64 in this case because you cannot directly access the top 64-bit of the Quad registers, but I think you should be able to replace it with:

```
INS V15.S[0], V11.S[0]
INS V15.S[2], V11.S[2]
```

Ref: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/INS_advsimd_elt_vector.html

Comment: I am not sure if I am quite clear on your answer. `"EXT v15.8, v15.8, v11.8, #4"` seems to operate extract function on the lower half of the vector registers (I mean `v15.d[0]` and `v11.d[0]`). However there's no way around that I can do this operation on the second half of these vectors (I mean `v15.d[1]` and `v11.d[1]`). In ARMv7, as you can see in my question, we can simply do this with `"vext.8 d31, d31, d23, #4 \n\t"`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found your answer or if this is your intended goal:

As @Dric512 indicated, I think you can use the SIMD Data Movement instruction, INS.

In the example below, we insert numbers 3 and 2 into vectors 10 and 11 within the 32-bit lanes, respectively.

We then insert the respective elements into both 32-bit lanes of vector 15; thereby resulting in all bits going into a 64-bit lane of vector 15.

```
 mov w1, 3                                                                                                                                                   
 mov w2, 2                                                                                                                                                   

 ins v10.s[0], w1                                                                                                                                            
 ins v11.s[1], w2                                                                                                                                            

 ins v15.s[1], v11.s[1]                                                                                                                                      
 ins v15.s[0], v10.s[0]
```

Below are gdb results using p/t... to display $v10.s.s, $v11.s.s, $v15.s.s in base 2 then a final p/t $v15.d.s show the 64-bit bit pattern. I'm not sure if this helps but maybe it will prime the pump.

```
67              mov w1, 3
(gdb) si
$82 = {0, 0, 0, 0}
$83 = {0, 0, 0, 0}
$84 = {0, 0, 0, 0}
68              mov w2, 2
(gdb)
$85 = {0, 0, 0, 0}
$86 = {0, 0, 0, 0}
$87 = {0, 0, 0, 0}
70              ins v10.s[0], w1
(gdb)
$88 = {11, 0, 0, 0}
$89 = {0, 0, 0, 0}
$90 = {0, 0, 0, 0}
71              ins v11.s[1], w2
(gdb)
$91 = {11, 0, 0, 0}
$92 = {0, 10, 0, 0}
$93 = {0, 0, 0, 0}
73              ins v15.s[1], v11.s[1]
(gdb)
$94 = {11, 0, 0, 0}
$95 = {0, 10, 0, 0}
$96 = {0, 10, 0, 0}
74              ins v15.s[0], v10.s[0]
(gdb)
$97 = {11, 0, 0, 0}
$98 = {0, 10, 0, 0}
$99 = {11, 10, 0, 0}
.exit0 () at stuff.s:78
78      _exit
(gdb) p/t $v15.d.s
$100 = {1000000000000000000000000000000011, 0}
```